# How can I send ether

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, addresses, address.transfer

Hey guys I am a beginer on Solidity. I write a function and try to send ether on remix accounts and check balances this accounts. But I can't connect accounts I think because when I check balance of my first account function return to me 0

What should I do? Can anyone help me?

Here's the code :

```
{
address myaddress;
mapping (address => uint256) public balances;

constructor() public {
    myaddress = msg.sender;
}
//uint amount =0;

function send(address from_address,address to_address, uint amount) public {
    require(amount <= balances[msg.sender], "Insufficient balance.");
    balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
    balances[to_address] += amount;
    //emit Sent(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted looks similar to an ERC20 token transfer, not an ether transfer. These two types of transfers are handled differently in solidity.

---

To transfer ETH, you need to use the <strike>send()</strike> [transfer()](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=transfer#address-related) function (see smarx's comment for strikethrough clarification). When using this function, the appropriate amount of ETH must already live in the contract or a user must send the appropriate amount of ETH in the transaction.

If the latter method is chosen, the function will need the `payable` modifier on it. Additionally, the address being sent to will need to be `payable` as well.

An ERC20 token transfer, on the other hand, is more of a mapping state change than an actual transfer. When you send an ERC20 token, the EVM decrements your current `balance` and increments the receiver's `balance`. Read more about ERC20 in [the wiki page](https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard).

Comment: Generally people should use `transfer`, not `send`. (If you're in a rare case where `send` is better for you, you probably know the difference.)